# lost connection to device when I use Image Picker for gallery in flutter

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

I faced a problem when I use Image Picker for pick Image from gallery
my phone stop
and it told me that "Lost connection to device "-_-..Although it works for pick image from camera
what should I do??
and I try some solutions from the internet and I don't find any thing help me in my problem...
This is a code of function
`enter code here`

```
File? _image;
 bool isSelected =false;
  final imagePicker=ImagePicker();
  Future uploadImage(ImageSource src) async{
    try{
      final selectedImage = await imagePicker.pickImage(source:src);
      if (selectedImage == null) return;

      final imagetemporary = File(selectedImage.path);
      setState(() => _image = imagetemporary);
    }on PlatformException catch(e){
      print('failed to pick image :$e');
    }
  }
```

this is the code I use my function in it :
`enter code here`

```
ProfileWidget(
              imgPath: user.imgPath,
              isEdit:true,
              isSelected: _image!=null?true:false,
              imageFile: _image!=null?_image:null,
              onClicked: (){
                var ad =AlertDialog(
                  title: const Text('Choose Picture from :',),
                  content: Container(
                    height: 22.h,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Divider(color: lbb,),
                        Container(
                          height:8.h,
                          color: gray,
                          child: ListTile(
                            leading: const Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                            title:  const Text('Camera'),
                            onTap: (){
                              uploadImage(ImageSource.camera);
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 1.h,),
                        Container(
                          height: 8.h,
                          color: gray,
                          child: ListTile(
                            leading:const  Icon(Icons.image),
                            title: const Text('Gallery'),
                            onTap: (){
                             uploadImage(ImageSource.gallery);
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
               showDialog(context: context, builder:(context)=>ad );
              }
          ),
```

Comment: I meet "lost connection to device" when loading multiple files.  The problem can be avoided with "cachedHeight". It decreases memory usage.  For example, 

final thumbnail = Image.file(File(path), height: 56, fit: BoxFit.fitHeight, cacheHeight: 128);

Comment: thank you for your replay .... I solved my problem with downloading an application on my device called "MobiDrive" and I used it for loading Image ..and its work.